# How to Customize the URL Structure for a Specific Custom Post Type in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently building a site and have received a request to customize the URL structure display. Here's my current setup:

1. In the wp-admin dashboard, the general permalinks structure setting is set to 'Post name'.
2. I've created a custom post type called 'information', and here is the code:

```
function create_custom_post_type_information() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __( 'お知らせ一覧' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'お知らせ一覧' ),
        'menu_name'          => __( 'お知らせ一覧' ),
        'add_new'            => __( '新規追加' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( '新しいお知らせ一覧を追加' ),
        'edit'               => __( '編集' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'お知らせ一覧の編集' ),
        'new_item'           => __( '新しいお知らせ一覧' ),
        'view'               => __( '表示' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'お知らせ一覧を表示' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'お知らせ一覧を検索' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'お知らせ一覧が見つかりません' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'ゴミ箱にお知らせ一覧が見つかりません' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'public'              => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'revisions' ),
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'information'),
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'information', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_post_type_information' );

// カスタムタクソノミー：お知らせ一覧のカテゴリー / information_category
function create_custom_taxonomy_information_category() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => __( 'お知らせ一覧カテゴリー' ),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'お知らせ一覧カテゴリー' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'お知らせ一覧カテゴリーを検索' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'すべてのお知らせ一覧カテゴリー' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( '親カテゴリー' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( '親カテゴリー:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'お知らせ一覧カテゴリーを編集' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'お知らせ一覧カテゴリーを更新' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'お知らせ一覧カテゴリーを追加' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( '新しいお知らせ一覧カテゴリー' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'info-ctg' ),
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'info_ctg', array( 'information' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_custom_taxonomy_information_category' );
```

3. I've also created a new page with the slug name 'information'. Therefore, I set `has_archive' => false,` and handled pagination with this code:

`add_rewrite_rule( 'information/page/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=information&paged=$matches[1]', 'top' );`

What I've done so far works, but now I'm confused about how to customize only this post to be formatted like this:

> /information/yyyy/mm/dd/post_id

I've tried the following code, but it didn't work and displayed a 404 page:

```
function custom_permalink_structure($permalink, $post) {
    // For single information posts
    if ($post->post_type === 'information') {
        $permalink = home_url('/information/' . date('Y/m/d', strtotime($post->post_date)) . '/' . $post->ID);
    }

    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_permalink_structure', 10, 2);
```

I've been following this [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22490](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/mixing-custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-rewrite-structures/22490#22490) but it didn't work.

Can anyone please help me with customizing the structure? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue Reason:

First and foremost, lets I explain why this issue occurred. Because you didn't implement the second half of the solution, i.e. rewrite rule.

### Pretty URL:

The first half, i.e. [`post_type_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) only deals with URL of a particular post of custom post type. Which means you done creating custom URL or pretty URL.

FYI, WP provide some inbuilt [structure tags](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customize-permalinks/#structure-tags-1) you can make use of that when building pretty link instead of `date('Y/m/d', strtotime($post->post_date))` but it's up to you because your way of implementation also technically correct, but most people like to use structure tags if it is available.

### Rewrite Rules:

The second half or the missed part is you didn't add rewrite rule logic which is processed by web server like Apache to map/route the URL and its execution point.

**Important:**
To see this code get actioned, you have to flush the rewrite rule. You can do that in many ways my preference is WP CLI command `wp rewrite flush`

If you want to flush rules programmatically for e.g. you created plugin or theme or drop-in and sharing it public then use this function [flush_rewrite_rules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/) to flush out the old rewrite rule. But make sure this should execute only required either using [conditional guard clause](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/123406/104269) or certain point of execution hooks like plugin [activation and deactivation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/123403/104269).

The rule can be added in various ways, but I prefer [`{$permastructname}_rewrite_rules`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/permastructname_rewrite_rules/) because it fetches only specific structname rules only which is easy on the eyes during debugging instead of seeing the whole rules at a time (just the personal preference always choose more specific hooks than generic hooks to save me from frustrated debugging)

This hook roughly translated to `information_rewrite_rules` in our context where `information` is the post type which is prefixed to `_rewrite_rules`.

Solution is:

```
function custom_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $rules['information/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=information&p=$matches[4]';
    return $rules;
}
add_filter( 'information_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules', 20 );
```

Lets I explain the code of the hook `information_rewrite_rules` callback.

1. The custom regex pattern `information/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,})/?$` is mapped to `index.php?post_type=information&p=$matches[4]`
2. Which renders the individual post (`p=$matches[4]`) of post type (`post_type=information`)
3. Here the `p` and `post_type` of public query variables, which means we can pass it directly in URL query string (Complete list https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars)

To see about the rule and its regex explanation, follow this link and see explanation panel on the right side:
https://regex101.com/r/3Eyk32/1

---

Want to learn more about WP Rewrite API then take a look at these links:

1. https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/rewrite/
2. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/
3. Third party tutorial [Mastering WordPress rewrite rules](https://brightminded.com/blog/mastering-wordpress-rewrite-rules/)

---

Facing trouble or want to debug for better understanding I will suggest these two plugins:

1. https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/
2. https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

The rewrite analyzer is very outdated plugin and both are development related plugin, therefore don't use it in production.

[image: Rewrite Analyzer]
[image: Query Monitor]